# Data Driven Framework: Web/Desktop Camelot V Django etc

Tags: python, database, frameworks, web2py

Wanting to get some feedback on frameworks. Web/Desktop. It doesn't seem to be much difference in most respects expect web can go everywhere and desktop can't.

For a small user base however using database database driven application, where 70% input would come from files, and 30% for the user. Would I get more benefit from a desktop based solution like Camelot [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/index.html) or Dabo & Pyjamas matched against say Django, Grok, Plone or Pyramid?

I was going to learn django based largely on docs [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) and apparent ease of learning. Thought i should check first before diving in if its the most appropriate.

For data driven project where display/input/reporting facilites(charts/graphs) required is there a best fit or a "better fit". Can't see that I would loose anything by using a web framework for this these days, but where the desired output is more "business" logic based rather than a web page which avenue should i go web v desktop and if either better option?

Edit: I have found another possible solution/answer web2py [web2py](http://web2py.com/examples/default/what)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find web2py very easy to learn and use. Note, if desired, you can easily distribute your web2py app to individual users for installation on their own computer like a desktop app (using the browser as the user interface) -- see [here](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/12#How-to-Distribute-your-Applications-as-Binaries). The users don't need to have anything else installed on their computer (not even Python), and web2py itself doesn't require installation, just unzipping.